# How do I select a LASTDATE() in TSQL when using a INNER JOINed table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

So, here it goes: I have a table that is returning timespans for a user ID. Unfortunately, it is returning duplicated timespans for some users (i.e. some users appear more than once in the results, because they have duplicated records in the query).

I want to select just the most recent timespan from the user results, for every user in the result set. I tried building a query that would SORT BY(), but that hasn't proven fruitful. I think I am on the right track with that, but perhaps not.

Anyways, here is a sample summary of the output that I am trying to winnow out:

```
User        Activity 1                Activity1 ID  Activity 2               Activity2 ID
User 1      01-01-2009 - 12-31-2010   100.00        03-02-2009 - 05-05-2009  500.01
User 1      01-06-2009 - 12-31-2010   100.01        03-02-2009 - 05-05-2009  500.01
User 2      06-01-2009 - 12-31-2010   200.00        06-06-2010 - 03-03-2011  501.01
```

What I would like to do is return just the first 'User 1' category (or more specifically, the tuple with the longest timespan). I am using MS SQL Server (TSQL), and it doesn't support Temporal data structures (yet), but should in 2012.

Any thoughts from the collective?

Comment: Please improve the wording of your question, it is a little difficult to figure out exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I can work on revising the wording, but Telerian seemed to understand the context pretty well.

Comment: It was a bit confusing, but the point is that you want to find the top 1 record per group based on some sort within the group. That was rather difficult to do in prior versions of Sql Server, but it's relatively easy these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking to "partition" your query.
These should help:

[The OVER clause.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

[The ROW_NUMBER function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

[Some interesting examples.](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/28/60146.aspx)

Comment: I think this is indeed what I was looking for. It looks as if the OVER command will do exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order it by timespans try to substract the end date from start date.
For example:

```
declare @Start DateTime, @End DateTime
set @Start = '20100131'
set @End = '20100502'

select @Start, @End
select cast(@End - @Start as int)
```

this will return number 92. 
I you use

```
select top 1 
... 
order by cast(@End - @Start as int) desc
```

It should work fine.
As Telarian wrote using partitioning would be helpful too.